# Re-write source IP to vlan tagged IP

Tags: route, vlan, iptables-redirect

[image: Output of ip r s for PC2][image: Output of ip r s FOR PC1]My setup is as follows:

PC1: IP of normal interface 10.0.0.11
IP of vlan interface   11.0.0.11

PC2: IP of normal interface 10.0.0.12
IP of vlan interface   11.0.0.12

I can `ping` 11.0.0.12 with no issues. Now I want to force `ping` to use interface 10.0.0.11 when pinging 11.0.0.12. To do this I used `ping -I 10.0.0.11 11.0.0.12`. Unfortunately, my attempts were not successful. I tried using `POSTROUTING` and `INPUT` chain command as follows:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.11 -j SNAT --to-source 11.0.0.11. 
sudo iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.11 -j SNAT --to-source 11.0.0.11
```

When I run `tcpdump` I still do not see the source IP change. The source IP is still 10.0.0.11 (instead of the expected 11.0.0.11) and there is no response from PC2.

May you please help me with what rule is suitable for this kind of problem. I'm not sure if vlans work differently.

Comment: Is it hte sam VLAN (I assume yes), can you edit your post with result from `ip r s` from both PCs ?

Comment: Question updated accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search enginre results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.